# Convergence or divergence of a series test

Tags: sequences-and-series

Test the convergence or divergence of this series whose $n^{\text{th}}$ term is:
$$(\ln n)^{-\ln(\ln n)},$$
i.e. Test the convergence or divergence of this series:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(\ln n)^{-\ln(\ln n)}.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote
$$a_n = \frac{1}{\big(\ln n\big)^{\ln\ln n}}$$

Two closely related solutions:

1. Integral Test:

$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_n$ converge or diverges with 
$$\int_2^\infty \frac{dx}{\big(\ln x\big)^{\ln\ln x}}
\overset{\substack{x\equiv e^u,\\dx = e^u\,du\\\vphantom{x}}}{=\mkern-3mu=\mkern-3mu=\mkern-3mu=} 
\int_{\ln 2}^{\infty} \frac{e^u \;du}{u^{\ln u}}
= \int_{\ln 2}^{\infty} \frac{e^u}{e^{(\ln u)^2}}\;du
= \int_{\ln 2}^{\infty} \underbrace{e^{u - (\ln u)^2}}_{\to\infty}\;du
= \infty$$
so it diverges.

2. Cauchy condensation test ($\sum a_n$ and $\sum 2^na_{2^n}$ converge or diverge together).

This is essentially the same argument. The sum convergence or divergence of the sum with terms

$$
b_n
= 2^na_{2^n}
= \frac{2^n}{\big( \ln 2^n \big)^{\ln\ln 2^n}}
> \frac{2^n}{\big( \ln e^n \big)^{\ln\ln e^n}}
= \frac{e^{n\ln 2}}{e^{(\ln n)^2}}
= e^{n\ln(2) -(\ln n)^2}
\to \infty
$$
as the polynomial in the exponent dominates and goes $\to\infty$. So $\sum b_n$ diverges, so $\sum a_n$ diverges.

Comment: Perfect one..  can it be done by cauchy?

Answer (score 0):

By [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)

$$ 0 \ \leq\ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)\ \leq\ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{n}f(2^{n})\ \leq\ 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)$$

we have

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac1{(\ln n)^{\ln(\ln n)}}
\ge\frac12 \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{(\ln 2^n)^{\ln(\ln 2^n)}}
=\frac12\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{(n\ln 2)^{{\ln(n\ln 2)}}}>\frac12\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{n^{{\ln(n\ln 2)}}}$$

and

$$\frac{2^n}{n^{{\ln(n\ln 2)}}}\to \infty$$

indeed

$$a_n=\frac{2^n}{n^{{\ln(n\ln 2)}}}\implies \sqrt[n] a_n=\frac{2}{n^{\frac{{\ln(n\ln 2)}}{n}}}\to 2$$

since

$$n^{\frac{{\ln(n\ln 2)}}{n}}=e^{ \frac{{\ln(n\ln 2)}\cdot\ln n}{n} }\to e^0=1$$

Comment: How can you say the sequence $\frac{2^n}{n^{{\ln(n\ln 2)}}}\to \infty $

Comment: @ÜnpredictableKaushik The best way is by root test.

Comment: I am not getting the limit value by root test?

Comment: @ÜnpredictableKaushik I add this step here in  a moment.

Comment: $$2^n / n^{\ln(n \ln 2)} = e^{n \ln(2)} / e^{\ln(n \ln 2) \cdot \ln n}
= e^{n \ln(2) - \ln(n \ln 2) \cdot \ln n}
$$ 
The exponent is then
$$n \ln(2) - (\ln n)^2 - \ln 2 \cdot \ln n \to \infty$$

Comment: How can you say that the exponent goes to infinity?

Comment: $n$ is polynomial and grows faster than $ln(n)^p$ for any $p$

Comment: How can we say that.. $ \frac{(ln n)}{n} $ is there I guess.. and the remaining part is constant.. can we deduce that from there?

Comment: @ÜnpredictableKaushik are you asking to me or to adfriedman? use the @ when the comments involve more people

Comment: To you sir @gimusi

Comment: I got you @adfriedman